# Making allegro5 project with CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, allegro5

Few days ago I downloaded clion to make a school project in C++ and Allegro5. First I used allegro installed with homebrew but it wasn't working so I compiled it by myself. Since I've never worked with CMake before it took me some time to include the libs and compile the project but I managed to do it. The problem is that when I try to run it it throws an error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __al_mangled_main
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/liballegro_main.5.0.dylib
Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/lib/liballegro_main.5.0.dylib
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(arkanoid)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES classes/main.cpp classes/ball.cpp classes/ball.h classes/block.cpp classes/block.h)

add_executable(arkanoid ${SOURCE_FILES})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( allegro/5.0.11/include )

LINK_DIRECTORIES( allegro/5.0.11/lib )


TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(arkanoid  allegro_acodec
                            allegro_audio
                            allegro_color
                            allegro_dialog
                            allegro_image
                            allegro_main
                            allegro_memfile
                            allegro_physfs
                            allegro_primitives
                            allegro_ttf
                            allegro_font
                            allegro)
```

And for now my main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    al_init();

    return 0;

}
```

I'm trying to build this project on OSX. I've searched for 2 days for the solution to my problem but with no results. Not many people are using CLion and even less use it with allegro5. Could anyone have a clue what this error even mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this one blew my mind. I don't know why I found solution only after asking on stackoverflow but I'm posting it for someone who might encounter simillar problem to mine. Change your main declaration from

```
int main()
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

and that's it. Really.

Comment: This is actually explicitly described in Getting Started Guide for Allegro: http://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.0.10/getting_started.html#the-main-function

Comment: Yeah, I really don't know how did I miss it. Really stupid mistake.